# Google App Engine Out Of Memory error - memory quota?

Tags: google-app-engine, out-of-memory

My Google App Engine application runs out of memory at about 100 MB. I need more. Looking at the list of quotas on my dashboard: https://appengine.google.com/dashboard/quotadetails
I didn't find anything about memory.

Is there a way to buy more memory allocation for my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it sounds like you need a "backend":

> App Engine Backends are instances of your application that are exempt
>   from request deadlines and have access to more memory (up to 1GB) and
>   CPU (up to 4.8GHz) than normal instances. They are designed for
>   applications that need faster performance, large amounts of
>   addressable memory, and continuous or long-running background
>   processes.
>   [...]
>   Backends share the handlers defined in app.yaml with the main
>   application version.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview.html#Billing_Quotas_and_Limits